# Set Radio Button checked in datatable with record from database

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a table of email_templates that can be assigned to an email. Only one can be assigned so there is a radio button in the datatable. 
When the user selects a template it saves the template_id in the emails table. 
[image: radio button image presentation]

When i open the email to edit it i would like for the templates table to have already selected the email template associated with that email.

here is my edit controller...

```
def edit
    @email_broadcast = EmailBroadcast.active.where("organization_id = ? and id = ?", current_users_user.organization_id, params[:id]).first

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json: EmailTemplatesDatatable.new(view_context, false) }
    end  
end
```

Any suggestions? Thank you!!

Comment: Can you be more precise what actually you want to do ?

Comment: @zauzaj i edited my question to be more specific, Thanks!

Comment: sorry but don't get last part:
```When i open the email to edit it i would like for the templates table to have already selected the email template associated with that email.

```

Comment: btw, you already get email template ( @email_broadcast) so you can use it on your template/view

Comment: @zauzaj the table `email_templates` is in the edit page of an email. In that table is where the user establishes the relationship between an email and  an email template. So when i open the email to edit it i would like for the `email_templates` table to have the selected email template for that email. Better? thanks again for the help.

Comment: @zauzaj email_broadcast can only have one email_template btw

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149495/discussion-between-zauzaj-and-quincosa).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@quincosa

You can do checking in `email_templates.each do |template|` loop, like `email.template_if&template.id`. When you have positive matching, that means you found appropriate template for that email and just set radio button `selected`.

Comment: can we https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149495/discussion-between-zauzaj-and-quincosa jump in the chat again